# Parsing error processing resource path jndi:/localhost/StrutsDataExport/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml

Tags: java, struts

Hi i get the following exception while starting the server `tomcat 6.0`

```
SEVERE: Parsing error processing resource path jndi:/localhost/StrutsDataExport/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in trailing section.
```

this is what is my `struts-config.xml`

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
          "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">

<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="UserForm" type="com.report.UserForm" />
    </form-beans>

    <global-exceptions>

    </global-exceptions>

    <global-forwards>
        <forward name="welcome" path="/Welcome.htm" />
    </global-forwards>

    <action-mappings>
        <action input="/" name="UserForm" path="/userAction" scope="session"
            type="com.report.UserAction">
            <forward name="success" path="/user.jsp" />
        </action>
        <action path="/Welcome" forward="/welcomeStruts.jsp"/>
    </action-mappings>

    <controller processorClass="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor" />

    <message-resources parameter="com/report/ApplicationResource" />


    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin">
        <set-property property="definitions-config" value="/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml" />
        <set-property property="moduleAware" value="true" />
    </plug-in>

    <!--
        ========================= Validator plugin
        =================================
    -->
    <plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
        <set-property property="pathnames"
            value="/WEB-INF/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/validation.xml" />
    </plug-in>

</struts-config>
    -->
`
```

I get the exception saying that i have a problem in struts-config file but i am unable to find, that is why i get the above exception while deploying, i am using netbeans IDE,Please help me to resolve this

Regards

Comment: There is a problem in your XML file at the end, or is it bad copy/paste ? See the `    -->` at the end of your file.

Comment: thanks for the post, it helped. now i get this exception `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application`

Comment: You may check this page in order to verify that displaytags is correctly installed for your project http://www.displaytag.org/10/install.html

Comment: `<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/displaytag.tld" prefix="display" %>` i get exception in this line, but i have jar file in /WEB-INF/lib

Comment: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 10 ``<jsp:forward page="UserAction.htm" />` i now get this exception

Answer (score 0):

As Alex mentionned the first problem is caused by a trailing " -->"

The second error `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://displaytag.sf.net cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application`
is caused by a wrong taglib uri declaration.

The solution would be to declare the taglib as such

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net/el" prefix="display" %>
```

instead of

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net/" prefix="display" %>
```